# Sidekiq sent duplicated emails asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq

I am following this tutorial: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2013/01/using-sidekiq-to-send-emails-asynchronously to send emails asynchronously. All is OK but the email is sent twice. I checked the console and it creates 1 job, but this job is sent twice, the same email each time. My method to send the email is this:

```
def high_value_filter
  if self.branch.vendor.high_value.to_i <= self.spent_value.to_i
    Alert.create(:table => "transactions", :item_id => self.id, :type_id => Alert::Type::TRANSACTION_HIGH_VALUE)
    ## Sent emails assynchronously if Redis connected
    if redis_connected?
      #MyMailer.delay.high_spent_value(self.branch ,self.consumer, self, self.current_user, self.host)
      MyMailer.delay.high_spent_value(self.branch ,self.consumer, self, self.current_user, self.host, self.branch.email) if self.branch.email.present? 
    else
      MyMailer.high_spent_value(self.branch ,self.consumer, self, self.current_user, self.host)
      MyMailer.high_spent_value(self.branch ,self.consumer, self, self.current_user, self.host, self.branch.email) if self.branch.email.present?
    end
  end
end
```

and my mailer is:

```
def high_spent_value(branch ,consumer, transaction, current_user, host, receiver = "email@hotmail.com")
  @branch = branch
  @consumer = consumer
  @transaction = transaction
  @user = current_user
  @host = host
  mail(to: receiver, subject: "Valor alto gasto em #{@branch.vendor.name}").deliver
end
```

OBS: I try remove the deliver method but the duplication persist, please someone now what happens ?

Comment: Is it because you have not commented out the first line in the else block?